# Spark subtractByKey increases RDD cached memory size

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I've found a very strange behavior for Apache Spark RDD's (spark 1.6.0 with scala 2.11):

When i use subtractByKey on an RDD the resulting RDD should be of equal or smaller size. What i get is an RDD that takes even more space in memory:

```
//Initialize first RDD
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Array((1,1),(2,2),(3,3))).cache()

//dummy action to cache it => size according to webgui: 184 Bytes
rdd1.first

//Initialize RDD to subtract (empty RDD should result in no change for rdd1)
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Array[(Int,Int)]())

//perform subtraction
val rdd3 = rdd1.subtractByKey(rdd2).cache()

//dummy action to cache rdd3 => size according to webgui: 208 Bytes
rdd3.first
```

I frist realized this strange behaviour for an RDD of ~200k rows and size 1.3 GB that scaled up to more than 2 GB after subtraction

Edit: Tried the example above with more values(10k) => same behaviour. The size increases by ~1.6 times. Also reduceByKey seems to have a similar effect.

When i create an RDD by

```
sc.paralellize(rdd3.collect())
```

the size is the same as for *rdd3*, so the increased size carries over even if it's extracted from RDD.